# replacing all single quotes with double quotes in a string - groovy

Tags: string, groovy

I need to replace all single quotes in a string with double quotes, (one way to use replaceAll) but how do I take care of the escapes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea what you mean about taking care of the escapes...

This works fine:

```
assert "first ' another \'".replaceAll( /'/, '"' ) == "first \" another \""
```

The escapes are there for the parser...they are not actually in the String...

Comment: @pri_dev They're needed so the parser can read the string correctly, but they are not actually included in the string itself...  Unless you're generating stuff which is going to be passed back into the groovy parser, you don't need to worry about them

Comment: Just an FYI: If you are simply replacing one character (or string) with another, there's no reason to use regular expressions.  Using Java's [`myString.replace("'", '"')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) would be more efficient in general.  A micro-optimization, to be sure, but avoids the overhead of building a regex.